# In ASP.NET MVC, is it risky to use the controller as an argument in the constructor for a ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In my application, on all my pages, I need to know if the user is logged in and (if so) the username.

For convenience, I have been including `System.Web.Mvc` and passing in the `Controller` in the constructor to my base class of `PageViewModel` so that I can set the model's `UserIsLoggedIn` and `LoggedInUsername` based on the controller. I do not maintain a reference to the controller in the `ViewModel`, so it is only used in the constructor.

Is this a common practice? If not, how do you fill in your view model from the controller's context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find if the user is logged in, you don't need to pass the controller around.

Depending on where you are in the app you could use `HttpContext.Current.User` to find that out.

Specifically try using `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` to check if they are logged in.

And use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` to get their username

And when you say "Pages" i assume you mean views ... the User object is already available in the view, you can simply say `@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` or `@User.Identity.Name`

Comment: Is it preferable to reference the `HttpContext` from the `cshtml` file rather than prefilling it in the view model?

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos You don't even need to reference it any more .. the object you are looking for is already available to the view. the User object which contains login status and username etc.